# Is there way to list availabe options to user select and input in Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es

I’m trying to design bot for web application using API.AI1 and webhooks, I want to provide the list of option to user select and input like Quick replies.

For example

Hi! My name is Eva and I’m a Chatbot. I can help you.

Then second automatic response like

Bank account
my Credit card
Application status
Debit card
Then user select the option and give the response from corresponding Intents

Any help …?

Comment: You could use the list class https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/nodejs/List

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi Dialogflow allows you to list several options through rich messaging, you can find all documentation at this address: https://dialogflow.com/docs/rich-messages#quick_replies

Answer (score 1):

You can use Suggestion class for that. If you are using node.js you can do the following.

Create a handler for your intent

```
function myCustomHandler(agent) {
  agent.add(`Please choose an option`);
  agent.add(new Suggestion(`Option1`));
  agent.add(new Suggestion(`Option2`));
}
```

and then map your intent with this handler

```
let intentMap = new Map();
intentMap.set('university', myCustomHandler);
```

Don't forget to enable this webhook under the Fulfillment section of your intent.

This is an example result (integrated with slack):

[image: dialogflow_options]